# Are there any results that state when expectations of products about the mean will be zero or will be a product of central moments?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value, independence

Are there any general results that say when the expected value of a product of two independent random variables about their means is zero or reduces to a product of central moments?

For instance, let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. We have the following central moments:
\begin{align*}
E\left[(X - E[X])(Y - E[Y]) \right] &= \text{Cov}(X,Y) \\
\\
E\left[(X - E[X])^2(Y - E[Y]) \right] &= E\left[(X - E[X])(Y - E[Y])^2 \right] = 0 \\
\\
E\left[(X - E[X])^2(Y - E[Y])^2 \right] &= \sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2
\end{align*}

Can we generalize what $E\left[(X - E[X])^i (Y - E[Y])^j \right]$ will be?

My intuition is that if one of $i$ or $j$ is odd and the other is even, then $E\left[(X - E[X])^i(Y - E[Y])^j \right] = 0$, but if both are even then $E\left[(X - E[X])^i(Y - E[Y])^j \right] = \mu_{X,i} \mu_{Y,j}$, where $\mu_{X,i}$ and $\mu_{Y,j}$ are the $i$th and $j$th central moments of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E\left[(X - E[X])^i (Y - E[Y])^j \right]=E\left[ (X - E[X])^i\right]E\left[(Y - E[Y])^j \right]$ which you suggest are $\mu_i \mu_j$ (confusing unless $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed). Your parity guess would only work if $E\left[ (X - E[X])^i \right]=0$ or $E\left[(Y - E[Y])^j \right]=0$ for example if they were symmetrically distributed about their means (or if $i=1$ or $j=1$)

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comment. I tried the case for $i=3$ and $j=2$ and didn't get $0$ as I would have previously guessed. So I believe you are right about requiring $E\left[ (X - E[X])^i \right]=0$ or $E\left[(Y - E[Y])^j \right]=0$.
 
Also, I changed the issue with the notation of the central moments that you pointed out.